# Can adding equals() and hashCode() method spoil something

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

Is it possible that adding `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods will break already existing code?

I have a class with 3 fields, getters and setters:

```
public class Person {
private final String name;
private final List<Friend> friends;
private final Integer age;
```

to test this class I used: `isEqualToComparingFieldByField()` method to compare two `Person` objects instead of adding `equals()` and `hashCode()`. Other solution is to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` and use `assertEquals()` to compare these object but can I be totally sure that it won't break anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can I be totally sure that it won't break anything?

No. You're changing the meaning of equality from reference identity to a sort of value equality. You'll break anything relying on the current behaviour. For example, here's some valid code:

```
Person person1 = new Person("Foo", 100);
Person person2 = new Person("Foo", 100);
// This is fine. Two distinct Person objects will never be equal...
if (person1.equals(person2)) {
    launchNuclearMissiles();
}
```

Your proposed change would break that.

Do you *actually* have code like that? It's hard to tell.

More likely, if you want to change `hashCode` to include hashes from the `List<Friend>`, you could very easily break code unless the type is actually immutable. For example:

```
Map<Person, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Person person = new Person("Foo", 100);
map.put(person, "Some value");

// If this changes the result of hashCode()...
person.addFriend(new Friend("Bar"));
// ... then you may not be able to find even the same object in the map.
System.out.println(map.get(person));
```

Fundamentally, you need to be aware of what other code uses `Person`, so you know what it's relying on. If `Person` is immutable, that makes life *much* simpler because you don't need to worry about the second kind of problem. (Overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()` for mutable types is a fundamentally treacherous business.)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on where and how you have used the person object. For example if you store person in HashSet, HashMap etc like data structure then it may behave differently. However, it is always recommended to override those methods if you are using any data-structure which uses hash and equals.

Answer (score 0):

You should always override those methods when you create your custom class. If you don't then implementations from Object class are used, and those implementations rely on reference - not on values of fields in objects of your custom class.

If you create two identical objects of your custom class and you use equals() method from Object class to compare them, you will get 'false' as a result. That's because even though those objects are identical, they contain different references.

Comment: "You should always override those methods when you create your custom class" - do you mean you override `equals` and `hashCode` on *every* class you write? IMO it really doesn't make sense for all classes - only natural "value" classes, and ideally only immutable ones, too.

Comment: I meant that it's probably better to override those methods when you're not sure, but you've got a good point. I'll keep that in mind.